# Include Page Specific Styles in Middleman

Tags: erb, middleman

I have a layout in the current version of Middleman (3.0.14). I would like to pulling page specific stylesheets or script if they exist.

In the layout I currently have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global", data.page.stylesheet %>
```

and in the YAML front matter I have:

```
stylesheet: homepage
```

The issue I'm having is that I would like to have the CSS render only if there is a stylesheet tag in the YAML from matter. Currently what happens is if there is no stylesheet tag in the YAML front matter it just renders a blank .css file.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does ...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global", (data.page.stylesheet ? data.page.stylesheet : {}) %>
```

... do the trick for you? As the 'stylesheet' key might be not set correctly within the Front Matter (`stylesheet:` or `stylesheet: ""`) you could even do some more checks:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global", ((data.page.has_key?('stylesheet') && ! data.page.stylesheet.nil? && ! data.page.stylesheet.empty?) ? data.page.stylesheet : {}) %>
```

Comment: Excellent! The first solution worked great! 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global", (data.page.stylesheet ? data.page.stylesheet : {}) %>`